# Как отличить базовый класс от его предка?

Tags: c#, ооп, наследование

```
public class Shape { }
public class Circle : Shape { }

class Program
{
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Circle circle = new Circle();
            Console.WriteLine(circle.GetType().Name);
            Shape shape = circle;
            Console.WriteLine(shape.GetType().Name); // - Можно ли как то получить исходный тип shape? 
            Circle circle2 = (Circle)shape;
            Console.WriteLine(circle2.GetType().Name);
        }
}

Результат:
Circle
Circle
Circle
```

Comment: А какой в этом смысл? То, что переменная объявлена как `Shape` вы и так знаете. А GetType позволяет узнать какой именно это Shape

Comment: Прикладного смысла нет, чисто теория. Интересно было бы узнать это не визуально по коду, а кодом в процессе выполнения. Можно или нет?

Comment: Ну, в качестве хохмы, можно так: `nameof(Shape)` )

Comment: У вас во всех случаях объект Circle, так что Shape не будет выведен

Comment: Понятно, что circle и shape это ссылка на один и тот же объект, но circle - это класс Circle, а shape - класс Shape. Это разные классы и разное поведение при наличии методов.

Comment: `circle.GetType().BaseType.Name`?

Comment: Базовый тип у circle и shape одинаковый, т.к.circle.GetType().GetHashCode() = shape.GetType().GetHashCode(). Получается, тип объектов одинаковый, а поведение объектов разное :\

Answer (score 0):

Можно:

```
void GetType<T>(T t) => Console.WriteLine(typeof(T));
```

Это работает т.к. на этапе компиляции будут определяться типы (а не в рантайме), на основании типа переменной, а не фактического объекта, который хранится в ней. Т.е.:

```
Shape shape = circle;
GetType(shape);
Circle circle2 = (Circle)shape;
GetType(circle2);
```

IL превратится в:

```
call void Program::GetType<class Shape>(!!0)
call void Program::GetType<class Circle>(!!0)
```

а уже рантам JIT-ом создаст два метода для каждого из типов, в которых и будет определяться он правильно.

Comment: В итоге typeof(T) - это тоже самое что typeof(Shape).
Хотелось бы всё таки узнать получить данные о типе через экземпляр, а не класс.

Comment: @inord777 так при вызове GetType(circle2) вы передает не тип, а экземпляр, да внутри он не используется, но он помогает компилятору определить тип

Comment: @inord777, можно конечно ещё создать некий интерфейс с `string GetTypeName();`, а уже к каждая реализация будет возвращать правильный тип

Comment: Не понятно... Зачем там параметр, когда он не используется?

Comment: для того чтобы определить тип, но фактические значение не нужно